# awk: Print out file 1 based on file2, and add column from file 2 and discard rows in file 1 depending on matching columns

Tags: awk

I'd like to print out file 1 based on file 2. Here are the job details:

First csv file, named as "file1_ab.csv":

```
a,  b,  20  
a1, b1, 5  
a2, b2, 8  
a5, b5, 30
```

second csv file, named as "file2_ab_compare.csv":

```
a,  b,  ID_100  
a4, b4, ID_400  
a2, b2, ID_200
```

I would like to use second csv file as filter to conditionally print out the first csv file following the logics like this:

1). if $1$2 of file 1 is the same as that file 2, such as row 1 of file1, print out row 1 of file1 plus the $3 of file 2 (forming column 4). For example:

```
a, b, 20, ID_100
```

2). if $1$2 of file 1 doesn't exist in that of file 2, I'd like to selectively print out that row of file 1 depending on the value of its $3.

for example:

$3 of row 2 of file 1 (5) is smaller than 15, then, I will discard this row. (so, row 2: a1,b1, 5 were not in the output file).

On the other hand,

$3 of row 4 of file 1 (30) is greater than 15, then, I will print out this row, and put "na" in column 4.

So, the final output should be like this:

```
a,  b,  20, ID_100  
a2, b2, 8,  ID_200  
a5, b5, 30, na
```

I wrote a code like this, named as "filter.awk":

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {FS=","}
NR==FNR{a[$1$2]=$3;next}
{
if ($1$2 in a) print $0","a[$1$2];
else
    if {$3 > 15} print $0",""na";}
    else {next}
}
```

I run this code like:

```
awk -f filter.awk file2_ab_compare.csv file1_ab.csv
```

But it said that there is syntax error. I have tried to modify this code many times by searching solutions on stackoverflow, but never got it worked out.

I would greatly appreciate your kind help!

BTW, is this kind work is too hard to use awk? Should I try Python in case like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=","} NR==FNR{a[$1$2]=$3;next} ($1$2 in a){print $0, a[$1$2]} !($1$2 in a){if($3>15){print $0, " na"}}' file2_ab_compare.csv file1_ab.csv
```

- `BEGIN{OFS=","}` sets the output field separator to comma.
- `NR==FNR{a[$1$2]=$3;next}` saves 3rd column as array value and $1$2 as key for the first input file.
- `($1$2 in a){print $0, a[$1$2]}` checks second inputs $1$2, if it exists in array, prints the whole line of second input file and the array value.
- `!($1$2 in a){if($3>15){print $0, " na"}}` if not in array, and 3rd column is bigger than 15, print the whole line and append `na`

Output:

```
a, b, 20, ID_100
a2, b2, 8, ID_200
a5, b5, 30, na
```

In your code, you mismatch and misuse curly braces, the corrected script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {FS=","}
NR==FNR{a[$1$2]=$3;next}
{
    if ($1$2 in a){
      print $0","a[$1$2];
    }else{
      if ($3 > 15){
         print $0",""na";
      }else{
        next
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Answers like this, if they work, amount to free consulting service. Please consider that the mission of stackoverflow is to help our fellow programmers improve their craft. Documenting your answer so that your code educates is FAR more useful than just spouting a one-liner, even if it works.

Comment: Hi Haifeng, Thanks a lot! Your code seems worked. But I just get the following output:                                                                                                  ,ID_100  
,ID_200  
a5,b5,30, na                              I am not sure why first print statement failed to printout the contents of rows from file 1. Thanks!

Comment: @ghoti Thanks, i was editing the answer the time you commented, now it's complete

Comment: @JeffZheng I tested my own command and also the corrected script of yours, both work. Have you tried both?

Comment: @Haifeng Zhang:   Thank you so much! But I still got the following output:   ,ID_100  
,ID_200  
a5,b5,30,na  .                                                                                                   I was wondering whether the awk on my Mac caused this issue. Thanks!

Comment: i was testing the command with your provided files content, everything is fine on my side. I am using MacOs too  i record it here https://asciinema.org/a/52diek37s0slpulrk3gbe3cws

Comment: @Haifeng Zhang  Not sure why, I double checked everything, but the  output is still:  ,ID_100  instead of "a, b, 20, ID_100" ,ID_200  instead of   "a2, b2, 8, ID_200"  for the first two rows of the output. The third row of output file is fine. I will let you know once I figure out what's going on. Thank you so much!

Comment: it seems like you didn't print `$0`， check your command carefully

Comment: @Haifeng Zhang  Thanks again for your great help! I found out the problem is that the csv files I prepared in excel somehow have problem (although I double checked these csv files in terminal using cat or less command, and never found anything wrong with these csv files). If I just used cat to create the csv files like you did, the code worked as it should. I am sorry for the confusion and will check out what's the problem with my csv files prepared in excel.

Comment: @JeffZheng glad you figured it out. Your file may contain hidden characters. you can remove them by `sed -i 's/[\d128-\d255]//g' original_file > new_file`. BTW, please check my answer as the answer due to it solved the issue you posted:)

Comment: @Haifeng Zhang. Thanks a lot. How should I check your answer as the correct answer? I tried to vote up your answer. By the way, I tried your sed command, it didn't solve the problem. But it provide me with important clues that somehow the digit numbers in first 3 rows of my first csv files (but not the 4th row) have issues. After the sed command (I have to remove -i parameter on my Mac though), the numbers in first 3 rows such as 5, 8 and 1 in a1, 2 in a2, all disappeared. Thanks!

Comment: @Haifeng Zhang: Thanks a lot! I noticed that the mark on the left side turned green after I clicked it.